# SQL update on current SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm new to SQL. I've been scouting to understand why this doesn't work but I can't find the solution.

The idea: I want to slect a random row that has `'seen = 0'`, 
display it and update it as `'seen = 1'` so it doesn't show anymore.

Here's the code:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM website WHERE seen in (0) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($plop = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
   $website_url = $plop['url'];
  };
 mysql_query('UPDATE website SET seen = 1 WHERE url = $website_url');
```

The SELECT displays correctly but the ***seen*** stays at 0

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Changing the quotes from single to double made it... Thanks!

```
mysql_query("UPDATE website SET seen = 1 WHERE url = '$website_url'");
```

Comment: probly needs quotes around the $website_url. either way, print/echo the update query and debug that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, [single quotes](https://php.net/language.types.string) mean that there is no interpolation. You should use double quotes, so that `$website_url` is replaced by its value in the second query.